# cucumber/capybara undefined method `visit'

Tags: testing, cucumber, capybara, integration-testing

I have a bundler application to perform cucumber tests for two of my applications named as "validation" and "recruiters". The directory structure of my test application is as follows:

```
root-folder
|_features
  |_recruiters
    |_recruitment_navigation.feature
    |_step_definitions
      |_recruitment_navigation_steps.rb
  |_validation
    |_FEATURE FILES
    |_step_definitions
      |_DEFINITION STEPS
  |_support
    |_env.rb
```

For the above directory structure. undefined method `visit` for `#<Object:0x870c080> (NoMethodError)` for every test which requires page visit.

But for the following directory structure, the tests are working fine:

```
root-folder
    |_features
      |_FEATURE FILES
      |_step_definitions
        |_DEFINITION STEPS
      |_support
        |_env.rb
```

Here is the env.rb file:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/cucumber'

require 'rspec/expectations'
require "ruby-debug"

Capybara.app_host = ENV["host"]
Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
World(Capybara)`enter code here`
```

Please help me with this. Is there any different kind of setup for Capybara that is required for first type of directory structure?

Comment: which version of cucumber are you using?

Comment: Ok, and how are you running the cucumber features? What command are you using?

Comment: @Tooky - cucumber host=<host-url> features/<feature file to be tested>

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell cucumber to correctly require the features directory when running features in a subfolder.

e.g.

```
cucumber host=<host-url> -r features features/recruiters/<feature file to be tested>
```

Should work I think.